# Python For Loop not iterating entire Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to loop through an entire Python Pandas DataFrame , but it does not seem to be looping through the entire DataFrame. It works for DataFrames of shorter lengths but not this one. Also, I am working in Jupyter Notebook.

I have added some print statements to try and debug.

```
def dropNotIn(df):

    print(df.shape)

    removedlist = []
    droplist = []

    for i, x in df.iterrows():
        rownum = i

    print(rownum)
    print(len(df))
```

Results for dropNotIn(df):

```
(59610, 9)
3449 --> Expected to be 59610
59610
```

Here is my df.head():

```
    date    attendance  venue_city  venue_state venue_name  away_team   home_team   away_points home_points
9   2015-12-13  1740.0  Chicago IL  McGrath-Phillips Arena  Arkansas-Little Rock    DePaul  66  44
13  2015-11-22  0.0 St. Thomas  NaN Virgin Islands Sport & Fitness Center   Tulsa   Indiana State   67  59
14  2014-12-04  3469.0  St. Bonaventure NY  Reilly Center   Buffalo St. Bonaventure 63  72
21  2015-11-20  1522.0  St. Thomas  NaN Virgin Islands Sport & Fitness Center   Hofstra Florida State   82  77
24  2014-11-23  NaN St. Thomas  NaN Virgin Islands Sport & Fitness Center   Gardner-Webb    Seton Hall  67  85
```

Comment: You'll have to share a representative data sample.

Comment: @pyeR_biz, added it.

Comment: Expect 3469, I did not see other values which you mention in  the desired output in your DataFrame. What are the conditions that need to be match for your desired output?

Comment: @hemanta, I've edited my question again to exclude the conditions. I guess my question does not really need to include the if statement.

Comment: I am trying to loop through the whole df. Each time through the loop, I am setting rownum = i, yet at the end, when I print rownum, it does not match with the size/len of the df.

Comment: print(df.index) can give you all rows and you can use len(df.index) to get the length. I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @hemanta I am trying to test if the loop is going through all the rows in the df.

Comment: But what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, `DataFrame.iterrows()` yields the *index* and the row. The index is something you control, and looking at your sample data you don't have an index that is densely-packed integers, but something else.

Try this code instead:

```
def dropNotIn(df):

    print(df.shape)

    removedlist = []
    droplist = []

    num_rows = 0
    for i, x in df.iterrows():
        num_rows += 1

    print(num_rows)
    print(len(df))
```

This counts the rows explicitly, instead of trying to use the index. If you really want to count rows during your operations, I'd suggest using the builtin function `enumerate` for this:

```
for num, (index, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
   pass
```

However, I suspect you probably don't want to do that, because when you're doing things with a dataframe you want to vectorize them as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The `iterrow` iterate around the index which is not equal to rownum. You may have some indexes with more than one row.

Try unpacking the `x,y = df.shape()` and iterate around a `range(x)`